# Saving coordinate values in a sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, save, coordinates

I need the code for a SQLite Database which saves the coordinate values (lat,long). 
I have a programm which shows my actual position on a map (OSM), know I have to save them in a SQLite Database,  my actual coordiantes(lat,long).

Answer (score 0):

SQLlite database comes with the command line utility which you can use save your data. There are number of open source tools sqlite database management tools that you can use to import csv file into sqlite